# Error en Python 2.7 html5lib

Tags: python, windows

estoy en windows 7, me da el siguiente error al ejecutar un programa en Python. Cual puede ser el problema? Ya instalé el modulo Six
Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Gustavo ¿Estás seguro de tener six instalado en ese intérprete?¿Tienes más intérpretes instalados en el sistema?

Comment: Esas rutas dan a entender que estás usando un intérprete empotrado en alguna aplicación. No haces nada instalando el módulo `six` en el sistema. Con tan escasa información, poco más se puede decir. ¿Puede ejecutar el intérprete e importar el módulo `six` desde él?

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, si, ahora instale el 3.7, pero como puedo hacer para instalar el six en el interprete?? yo me lo baje https://pypi.org/project/six/ descomprimi el archivo y luego abrí el CMD me fui a esa la carpeta y le di a setup.py install y dice que lo instala. Pero me sigue dando el error.

Comment: Ya lo pude arreglar gente, gracias! Instale el 2.7.15 y funcionó.

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses `pip` en vez de lanzar `setup.py` directamente para instalar módulos. Si tienes acceso a internet desde ese pc usa `pip` para instalar los módulos desde PyPI (`python -m pip install six` (se instalará en el intérprete que este asociado con python en el PATH) o `py -2.7 -m pip install six` si puedes usar PythonLauncher (si instalaste 3.7 lo tienes)). Si no tienes acceso a internet puedes descargarte el archivo y usar `pip` igualmente `py -2.7 -m pip install six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`